# Ошибка : модуль не найден

Tags: python

import graphics as gr

Пишет ошибку
import graphics as gr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'
В списке установленных есть[![список установленных модулей[image: ]]][2]

Comment: У вас может быть несколько питоновских окружений, разбирайтесь, как подключить то окружение, где установлен нужный модуль, туда, где вы библиотеку подключаете

Comment: хорошо, спасибо